# C++ change socket from broadcast to inaddr_any and bind

Tags: c++, sockets, bind, broadcast

Good day. I have socket that performs broadcast data exchange. After broadcast i need to use it with inaddr_any and than bind it. Should i recreate socket or it possible to perform it without reopening? Thank you!

Comment: Create a new socket.

Comment: I believe you can rebind a UDP socket, but you would have to test it. Why isn't it bound to INADDR_ANY in the first place? You can broadcast to or from that.

Comment: @EJP error 10047 when i try to use sendto() with INADDR_ANY. But if i set sin_addr.s_addr to INADDR_BROADCAST - sendto() works great

Comment: If i correctly understand this, after calling sendto() socket performs binding to addr. Is any way to rebind it?